# Is it possible to have Rails mask blog.mydomain.com as mydomain.com/blog?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, masking

I'd like to install a Wordpress blog that is associated with my domain. I am running a Ruby on Rails app on that domain so I know the easiest thing to do is set up a subdomain for the blog. However, I'd like to keep everything under the same roof, as it were.

How would I go about using Rails/Rack to serve blog.mydomain.com when going to mydomain.com/blog? My first thought was to perform some kind of mask or scrape the other domain and present the HTML as coming from /blog.

The app is running on Heroku, and I'm pretty sure how I would take care of this one an Apache server with .htaccess file (similar to what Wordpress does with permalinks), but I'm not sure how to accomplish this with the tools I have on hand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [rack-rewrite](http://rubygems.org/gems/rack-rewrite) to redirect requests to `mydomain.com/blog` to `blog.mydomain.com`.

Comment: rack-rewrite seems like a great tool, and I will be using it for other tasks, but it doesn't do exactly what I would like. The only way to have mydomain.com/blog be related to blog.mydomain.com with rack-rewrite is via a 301 which I'd prefer not to do. I'd like to blog using wordpress on a php host under the blog.mydomain.com subdomain, but have it appear to users that my blog is not on the subdomain but on mydomain.com/blog. Perhaps this is not possible or I am missing something about rack-rewrite?